# To comment out matches in Vim

Tags: vim

I would like to comment out each line which has the following match

```
^.*pdf
```

You need to somehow consider the situation by globbing. I try to make an object of the match by brackets.

I run unsuccessfully the following commands

```
%s/^(.*pdf)/^%$1/
```

and

```
%s/^(.*pdf)/^(%*$1)/
```

and

```
%s/^(.*pdf)/^%\$1/
```

**How can you comment out the matches in Vim?**

Comment: That * is not globbing, it is a Kleene closure and part of the regular expression pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what you exactly mean by "comment out" (are comments indicated by hashes, or what?) but it looks like what you want is to prepend a % sign. In that case,

```
:g/pdf/s/^/%/
```

should work ("on all lines containing 'pdf', change the start of the line to a %" is how you could read it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! - I did not know that you can combine the commands so nicely.

Comment: @Masi, the main power of Vim and related editors comes from the ability to combine the commands

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, I think you can get it working with:

```
:%s/^\(.*pdf\)/#\1/
```

or if you want to prepend '%' instead of '#':

```
:%s/^\(.*pdf\)/%\1/
```